# how to turn on gps automatically in flutter when using geolocation

Tags: flutter, permissions, gps, location

I am trying to get my current position using Geolocator package, but after pop up dialog shows to ask permission of my location and I click allow... my gps stills turn off and I have to turn it on manually, is there something that I should add in my code?

```
Position _mine;
   _myPosition() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _mine = position;
      });
      print(_mine.latitude);
    }).catchError((err) {

    });
  }
```

Comment: I can't see a problem in your code unless you didnt setup the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to forcefully turn your device GPS your can use [access_settings_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/access_settings_menu#-example-tab-) package and use `'ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS'` as the settings name

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  Position currentLocation;
  LatLng _latLng;
  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  return Geolocator()
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }
  getUserLocation() async {
      currentLocation = await locateUser();
      _latLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
  }
  LatLng getLatLng(){
      return _latLng;
  }
  updateLatLng(){
      getUserLocation();
  }
```